# MySQL Unique Multicolumn Index

Tags: mysql, indexing

Here is the scenario

In a CMS-like system that I am building I have to incorporate the ability to serve up different page content based on the IP location of the viewer.  To that end I have a MySQL table that contains, amongst other things, the columns

```
page - varchar (holds actual page content)
ciso - char(3) (holds an ISO country code)
```

When it is all working I should be able to have table entries along the lines of

```
page     ciso
--------------
lander   AUS
lander   USA
lander   FRA
....
```

What I want to be able to do is to ensure that each page/ciso pair is treated as a unique entry.  My MySQL skills are pretty basic - I use Indexes and I am aware that you can index on multiple columns but I have never used the capability (nor up to this point really appreciated why it might ever be needed).

I guess I could just suck it and see but it would be useful to know if an index on page & ciso will deliver the behavior I would like to see.  If so, are there any downsides to doing this?  If not, what other routes do I have (apart from using a unique autoincrementing row id column).  I'd much appreciate any help.

Comment: Testing that takes you approx. 1 minute. Why don't you just create a small test-table and see for yourself?

Comment: Have you tried declare UNIQUE(CONCAT(page, ciso)) ? or UNIQUE /help

Comment: Nope - mysql does not like CONCAT in the index spec.